# This error driving me nuts!!! (The WebResource.axd handler must be registered...)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Anyone have any clues on this error? This is appearing frequently in my ASP.NET MVC app.

[alt text http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/7360/errord.jpg](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/7360/errord.jpg)

Comment: Did you try registering the WebResource.axd handler?

Comment: Have you checked this http://blog.fredrikhaglund.se/blog/2007/09/27/the-mysterious-problem-with-webresourceaxd/

Comment: Well, this seems to be a solution. Let's try it.

http://blog.fredrikhaglund.se/blog/2008/08/26/solution-to-webresourceaxd-exception/

Comment: Are you using a WebResource att all, in your webapp? And have i.e. this service enabled in your IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added this line in your web.config's *httpHandlers*, before any other lines:

```
<add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True"/>
```